# update the string and preserve old data in array

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-replace-callback

I'm curious if it is possible to make this piece of code I've made a bit shorter and probably faster? The goal of this code below is to update the string by changing (and preserving) numbers in it with ordered replacements such as {#0}, {#1} and so on for each number found.

Also, keep that found numbers separately in array so we may recover information at any time.

The code below works but I believe it may be significantly optimized and hopefully done in one step.

```
$str = "Lnlhkjfs7834hfdhrf87whf4akuhf999re";//could be any string

$nums = array();
$count = 0;

$res = preg_replace_callback('/\d+/', function($match) use(&$count) {
    global $nums;
    $nums[] = $match[0];
    return "{#".($count++)."}";
}, $str);

print_r($str); // "Lnlhkjfs7834hfdhrf87whf4akuhf999re"

print_r($res); // "Lnlhkjfs{#0}hfdhrf{#1}whf{#2}akuhf{#3}re"

print_r($nums); // ( [0] => 7834    [1] => 87    [2] => 4    [3] => 999 )
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $str = "Lnlhkjfs7834hfdhrf87whf4akuhf999re";//could be any string

  $nums = array();
  $count = 0;

  $res = preg_replace_callback('/([0-9]+)/', function($match) use (&$count,&$nums) {
      $nums[] = $match[0];
      return "{#".($count++)."}";
  }, $str);

  print_r($str); // "Lnlhkjfs7834hfdhrf87whf4akuhf999re"

  print_r($res); // "Lnlhkjfs{#0}hfdhrf{#1}whf{#2}akuhf{#3}re"

  print_r($nums); // ( [0] => 7834    [1] => 87    [2] => 4    [3] => 999 )
```

After some little fixes it works.  `\d+` works too.

NOTE: Can not explain why `global $nums;` wont work. Maybe php internal issue/bug

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to add to @JustOnUnderMillions answer, just an other way that avoids the callback function:

```
$nums = [];

$res = preg_split('~([0-9]+)~', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

foreach ($res as $k => &$v) {
    if ( $k & 1 ) {
        $nums[] = $v;
        $v = '{#' . ($k >> 1) . '}';
    }
}

$res = implode('', $res);
```

Not shorter, but faster.